# How to Manage This Enter Key Event with three Different Situation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my aspx page, I am also using **two Modal Extender** but the main problem is that when modal popup extender comes in front then still **search button click** I want that **modal popups button should click on enter key** when popup is shown.

**I have set Default Enter Key Event in my page like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").bind("keydown", function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
    if (keycode == 13) {
      document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
```

and it's working good.

But the problem is that I have also two ModalPopupExtender on my Page
with `Id = ModalPopupExtender1` and `Id = ModalPopupExtender2`.

Now I want when My ModalPopupExtender1 called then button with  `ID = "btnMUpdate"` should click on enter key.

and when my ModalPopupExtender2 called then
button with  `ID = "btnConfirm"` should click on enter key.

Comment: Have you got a way to know if ModalPopupExtender1 or ModalPopupExtender2 is called like ModalPopupExtender1.isShown?

Comment: on  btnEdit_Click   this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();  and on  btnDelete_Click   this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show(); through C# backend Code

Comment: have you tried - `$('form').submit(function() {//your code});`

Comment: as i have Ajax Modal popup Extender i also tried in my panel setting Default Button but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i come across this and that worked fine for me

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender3"  runat="server"
    PopupControlID="PanelMsg" TargetControlID="lnkdummy3" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelMsg" DefaultButton="btnMSend"  runat="server"   Style="display: none;background-color:#e0e0e0">

  </asp:Panel>
```

given modal extender panel **`DefaultButton="btnMSend"`** and that worked fine

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
this.ModalPopupExtender1.add_showing(show1);
this.ModalPopupExtender2.add_showing(show2);
this.ModalPopupExtender1.add_hiding(hide1);  
this.ModalPopupExtender2.add_hiding(hide2);  
                $("body").bind("keydown", function (event) {
                    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
                    if (keycode == 13) {
    if (this.ModalPopupExtender1IsShown) {
                        document.getElementById('btnMUpdate').click();
    } else if (this.ModalPopupExtender2IsShown) {
                        document.getElementById('btnConfirm').click();
    } else {
                        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
    }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

function show1() {
    this.ModalPopupExtender1IsShown = true;
    }
function show2() {
    this.ModalPopupExtender2IsShown = true;
    }

function hide1() {
    this.ModalPopupExtender1IsShown = false;
    }
function hide2() {
    this.ModalPopupExtender2IsShown = false;
    }
```

On each ModalPopupExtender you can put a callback on show and hide events

Comment: how to put this call back ?

Comment: i mean in javascript function or c#?  in c# there is not any event called add_showing

Comment: hi Johnny_h sorry and thanks for Your time but i am getting confuse because i am not so much Familiar with script so can you please Update your  answer how to use it so that i can understand it better?